# Login screen disappears after a few seconds

Tags: login-screen

I'm on Ubuntu Studio 22.04.2 LTS (5.15.0-76 low latency 64)

When I boot up and get to the login screen, I have a few seconds to type the password ans enter before I get an empty black screen with a working cursor. After that happens, keyboard shortcuts such as Ctrl Alt F4 still work